# capturing Video through skype or open a packet in network

Tags: video-streaming, p2p, wireshark, skype, networkstream

I have a question that suppose two person are haveing live video call through skype.Is it possible for a third person `(may be ISP)` to monitor the video call?.Although skype video call is P2P.

1. Moreover I want to see the chain the of peer computers that connect me to the callee.tracert only allow me to check the route to specified destination..
2. Can I open a packet in a network by using Wireshark or any other software?Suppose two person are having live video call can I capture the packets between two and decrypt them to see the orignal message?
   These things are really important when we spend our time on Internet
   Any help will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: It is hopefully impossible - Skype claim that peer-to-peer traffic is encrypted. I would presume each end negotiates a session key like SSL so that there is no single key that will decrypt any session. These things cannot easily be checked, since Skype's software is closed-source, but on the other hand, it would be a difficult secret to keep if it were easily crackable. Equally, independent security researchers are likely looking at this issue periodically, and there'd be quite a hoo-haa if they found a serious vulnerability!

Comment: For the `tracert`, that may be possible - not my area though. Out of interest, what is your use case?

Comment: (Additional detail: you may be able to decrypt _your own_ sessions, if you can reverse-engineer Skype to get the key. But you cannot decrypt sessions belonging to other people - and neither should you be trying to do so, unless you are a legitimate security researcher `:)`).

Comment: @halfer If I want to decrypt my own session how i can do that?

Comment: As I mentioned above: reverse engineer the Skype executable to see how it works. This is highly expert-level stuff, and involves loading the binary into a low-level debugger to work out how the internal routines and data structures operate. That _might_ lead you to discover the decryption key for your own Skype sessions, which you can then use on the data stream to record it to disk. (Whilst terms of use are sometimes debatable, it is worth noting that this sort of activity is likely prohibited and could result in termination of your account.)

Comment: If you want to get the video/audio stream btw, it might be easier to hook into your own camera/microphone and record those directly, and to use a screen recorder to grab the video/audio from the other side. Much easier, imo, and won't get you into hot water with Skype (but be aware there are often legal regulations about recording third parties, depending on your territory).

Answer (score 2):

Cryptography works even if info goes through multiple nodes. So the answer to your question is no, knowing that Skype encrypts communications.

Yes, it is always possible to capture packets, but then again, if you don't have the secret key, you will not be able to decrypt the communication.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it would be possible because each software Skype etc has its own security algorithm,If this would be possible then people would easily going and capture other's information.Read skype architecture for further info